# how to send email to BCC reciepient using Server side Javascript for Xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am sending an email to some recipients using server side javascript. I am able to send an email to To recipient and CC recipient. Please guide how to send an email to BCC recipient using Server side Javascript for Xpages. My current code is

```
enter code here
var mailDoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
var mailBody = mailDoc.createMIMEEntity();
var mailSubject = mailBody.createHeader("Subject");
mailSubject.setHeaderVal("Test email");
stream.writeText( "This email is to be sent to BCC recipeints also");
mailBody.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html; charset=iso 8859-1",0);     
mailDoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo","ToUser@test.com");
mailDoc.replaceItemValue("CopyTo","CCUser@test.com");       
mailDoc.send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the field `BlindCopyTo` with the BCC recipients.

```
mailDoc.replaceItemValue("BlindCopyTo","BCCUser@test.com");
```